# What can an Object[] array hold?

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to the Java Programming language and had a question about arrays. `String[]` arrays hold strings. `Array[]` arrays hold other arrays. What about an `Object[]` array? Clearly, these would hold `Object`s. But, since `Object` is the superclass for everything in Java, does this mean an `Object[]` array can hold every type of `Object` in Java? In other words, can an array hold objects that are child classes of the object the array was created to hold? Can a `Number[]` array hold an integer?

Comment: Yes, an `Object[]` can hold any type of `Object` (you may have to cast it as such when you add one to the array) - a `Number[]`, however, can only hold `Number` objects (not native `int`s or `Integer` object (however if you cast them into `Number` objects, they will fit nicely)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes but you can learn a lot by trying it for yourself with a small program:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "String";
        Integer integer = new Integer(1);
        int integerPrimitive = 2;
        Float floatBoxed = new Float(1.23);
        float floatPrimitive = 1.23f;

        // Can hold different types inheriting from Object
        Object[] objects = new Object[] { 
                string, 
                integer, 
                integerPrimitive,
                floatBoxed, 
                floatPrimitive };

        // Can hold anything that inherits from Number; cannot hold a String
        Number[] numbers = new Number[] { 
                integer, 
                integerPrimitive, 
                floatBoxed,
                floatPrimitive };

        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("objects[" + i + "] = " + objects[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("numbers[" + i + "] = " + numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
objects[0] = String
objects[1] = 1
objects[2] = 2
objects[3] = 1.23
objects[4] = 1.23
numbers[0] = 1
numbers[1] = 2
numbers[2] = 1.23
numbers[3] = 1.23
```

The key to knowing what an array container can hold is first observing if the object types are the same or if the object is a sub-class of the array container type.

In your question if a [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) can hold an [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), you should see the inheritance of `Integer` in the Javadocs that it inherits from `Number`. You can also see that `Number` inherits from `Object`.

[image: Class Number]

[image: Class Integer]

Comment: Thanks.  This was an excellent explanation.  It is blowing my mind that you can put any differing types of data in an Object[] array.  I thought that was everything that Java stood against.